# Do Cauchy Sequences and Dedekind cuts have any real-world applications?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, cauchy-sequences, applications, dedekind-domain

Do Cauchy Sequences and Dedekind cuts have any real-world applications? Is their only purpose to complete the real numbers? What are the advantages and disadvantages of Cauchy Sequences versus Dedekind cuts?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "real world". As far as we know, spacetime it a continuum (i.e. is not discrete like $\mathbb{Z}$ or totally disconnected like $\mathbb{Q}$ or some such), so there are plenty of direct applications of this to physics. Physics would be very different if spacetime was not a continuum and so would the math therein. Derivatives, differential equations, etc. would be supplanted with something else altogether. Of course we know that in a non-"Planck" scale (i.e. zoomed out enough that the grainy nature doesn't matter), those are fine approximations.

Comment: The idea of completion using Cauchy sequences works for any metric space, while the idea of Dedekind cuts uses the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is ordered. The idea of Dedekind cuts generalizes for other ordered fields, and feels more related to set theory than to topology.

Comment: Isn't making reals form rationals real enough? In practice we cannot compute a (general) real number in it decimal expansion completely. All we can do is approximate. For example $x_{n+1}=\dfrac12\left(x_n+\dfrac{a}{x_n}\right)$ is an approximation scheme of $\sqrt{a}$ for any $a>0.$ Now the Cauchy sequence $x_1. x_2, x_3,\cdots$ approximate it.

Comment: One application: fun for mathematicians…